# Login jsp page disappears with local machine

Tags: internet-explorer, struts2, tiles

I am developing a project with `IBM Rad 8.5` on a `IBM Websphere 7.0` server.  I am using `Struts2` and `Tiles`.  When I enter to local machine url `https://nrijctdu8047932:9450/trails/welcome.action` in Chrome or Firefox the login page comes up fine but if I enter it in IE 11 the screen briefly shows and then goes to the `HTTP 404 Not Found` error page.  If I replace the machine name with local host (`https://localhost:9450/trails/welcome.action`) the login page works fine.  The `Struts` code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>

<!-- Set this to true to allow setting methods on submit buttons -->
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />

<!-- Exclude the logon servlet -->
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/logon"/>

<!-- Exclude the trailsproxy servlet -->
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/trailsproxy/*"/>

 <!-- Exclude the trailmap servlet -->
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/trailmap"/>

  <!-- Exclude the Rest Test servlet -->
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/RestTest"/>

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>  

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="validUser" class="gov.mo.dnr.interceptors.ValidUser"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="validUserStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="validUser"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
        <interceptor name="userInRole" class="gov.mo.dnr.interceptors.UserInRole">
            <param name="rolesList">Administrator,User,ReadOnly</param>
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="userInRoleStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="userInRole"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>


    <global-results>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">error</result>
        <result name="login" type="tiles">login</result>
        <result name="notAuthorized" type="tiles">error403</result>
        <result name="nodocumenterror" type="tiles">nodocumenterror</result>
    </global-results>


    <action name="welcome">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">welcome</result>
    </action>
```

The `Tiles` code is

```
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/pages/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Missouri State Parks Trail Inventory" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="navbar" value="/WEB-INF/pages/navbar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="welcome" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="navbar" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="" />
</definition>
```

When it displays, the login page has the following `HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Missouri State Parks Trail Inventory</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp1.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp2.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp3.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp4.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/trails.css" media="all" />

    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" media="all" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp5.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp6.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/pers.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp7.css" media="all" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/trails/css/dsp8.css" media="all" />
    <!--<![endif]-->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/trails/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Java Script for making IE 8 responsive -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/trails/javascript/respond.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-widget-header {
            background-color: #5B8923;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-57817 node-type-page phone iphone ios safari context-page" onload="checkGroup();">

    <header id="section-header" class="section section-header">
    <div id="zone-header-wrapper" class="zone-wrapper zone-header-wrapper clearfix"> 
    <div id="zone-header" class="zone zone-header clearfix container-24">
    <div class="grid-5 region region-branding" id="region-branding">
    <div class="region-inner region-branding-inner">
        <div class="branding-data clearfix">
            <div class="logo-img">
                <a href="https://mostateparks.com" rel="home" title="Missouri State Parks">
                    <img src="/trails/images/logo.png" alt="Missouri State Parks" id="logo" />
                </a>
            </div>

            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-19 region region-header-nav" id="region-header-nav">
<h1 id="applicationTitle">Trails Inventory System</h1>
        <div class="region-inner region-header-nav-inner">
            <div class="block block-search block-form block-search-form odd block-without-title" id="block-search-form">
                <div class="block-inner clearfix">
                   <div class="content clearfix">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="om-maximenu-main-menu" class="om-maximenu om-maximenu-no-style om-maximenu-block om-maximenu-row om-maximenu-block-down code-main-menu-imported">
                <div id="om-menu-main-menu-ul-wrapper" class="om-menu-ul-wrapper">
                    <ul id="om-menu-main-menu" class="om-menu">

                    </ul>
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
<section id="section-content" class="section section-content">
<div id="zone-content" class="zone zone-content clearfix container-24">
<div class="grid-24 region region-content" id="region-content">
<div class="region-inner region-content-inner">
<p>Welcome to the Trails Inventory System</p>
<p>NOTICE TO USERS<br><br>This is a State of Missouri computer system and is the property of the same. It is for authorized use only. Users (authorized or unauthorized) have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy. Any or all uses of this system and all files on this system may be intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected, and disclosed to authorized State and law enforcement personnel, as well as authorized officials of other agencies. By using this system, the user consents to such interception, monitoring, recording, copying, auditing, inspection, and disclosure at the discretion of authorized personnel. Unauthorized or improper use of this system may result in administrative disciplinary action and civil and criminal penalties. By continuing to use this system you indicate your awareness of and consent to these terms and conditions of use. Do not continue to use this system if you do not agree to the conditions stated in this warning.</p>
<div align="center">
<a href="/trails/logon"><strong>Login</strong></a>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>       
<script src="/trails/javascript/formatdate.js"></script>
<script src="/trails/javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/trails/javascript/dnrdatepicker.js"></script>    
<script src="/trails/javascript/utilities.js"></script>     
</body>
```

Comment: Does it work with Opera?

Comment: I don't have Opera loaded on my machine.

Comment: If it a browser issue then you should post html code

Comment: I did show the html generated by the jsp page.  Do you need to see the jsp code?

Comment: IE Conditional comments are depreciated in IE10 and higher. Use the File>Properties menu in IE to determine which IE security zone your pages/site map to.... Use the Emulation tab of dev tools to determine which IE Emulation mode was established and how it was established..test different IE versions (and IE Conditional comments)..Use the Networking tab to see which stylesheet was used and so which IE conditional comment was recognised and called. Use the View>Source menu to confirm that the request returned the source file but the needed stylesheets did not get called.

Comment: I don't see File>Properties.  Also, View>Source will just get me the source for the standard IE "webpage cannot be found" error page.